# RegEx match for a symbol at the beginning of a string, or the beginning of string itself

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that would catch a TLD in a group of subdomains. So I have this:

```
/\.?google\.com$/i
```

That should do the following matches:

```
sgoogle.com            -- no match
google.com             -- match
maps.google.com        -- match
job_s.map.google.com   -- match
place.google.com.eu    -- no match
```

This works, except for the first one, i.e. `sgoogle.com` that it matches as well, which it shouldn't.

So I'm curious, is there a way to specify where I do `\.?` to match either a dot or the beginning of string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Literally, your requirement would be:

```
(?:^|\.)google\.com$
```

But depending on your needs, this could be better (or not, you tell me):

```
\bgoogle\.com$
```

The `\b` means *word boundary*.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! I knew I was almost there :)

Comment: As for your `\b` suggestion, unfortunately it won't work because it won't account for dashes, like in `some-google.com`

Comment: OK I see, I thought you only wanted to match a fixed domain like google.com